# Will placing Google Ads at the bottom of the page have any effect?

Tags: google-adsense

What is the effect of placing Google Ads or any other kind at the bottom of the page?

With the ads as last element in the page, like placing ads below the half section of the page.

For example, some pages would be 2000px long and some would be more than 5000px so it would need more scrolling to get to the bottom...

Even if the user reaches the bottom, will they spend time looking at the ads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At one point, Google published a "heat map" on their site showing the best places to put ads.   They have since removed it because it made it appear that plastering your site with ads was the way to go.  **Don't** do that, use it to figure out where an effective placement or two for your site would be.  Here is a site that still has it and has revisited the question: http://www.vaughns-1-pagers.com/internet/google-heatmap-2.htm

As you can see, the most effective place for an ad is above the fold in the middle of the page right with the content.   Ads generally lose effectiveness as you go down the page.

The one exception to this is on article pages.   Putting an ad right at the end of the article near the bottom of the page can give the user something to do next after finishing reading.

Unless you have articles and put an ad right after the article, I would recommend putting the ad in a more visible place.

Comment: Thanks for validating my experience. I have a whole site where pretty much every page people land on is an "article page" and I have always been confused why the ad just at the bottom of the article performs best and I've never been able to equal that performance with ads at the top (even when placed between the article title and body).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that advertisers have the option in Google AdWords to choose only to show their ad's above the fold. Google can determine the screen resolution of a visitors browser and will display a advertisers ad in ad spaces above the fold if set to display that way. Otherwise the case studies in AdSense are a great way to find good ad spots on pages.

Answer (score 1):

googling with keywords `webpage hot places for ads`

give me this site http://www.clickspiration.com/resources/layout_info.php

You will have some effect from this ads but all depends on web page design.

[image]

For more try analize your site heatmap with http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/results?q=heatmap or http://www.crazyegg.com/ or google it with `Google Analytics + Heat Map Analytics`

And after this set ads in right place.